# What's the easiest way to provide an optional dependency?

Tags: ocaml

I have a little oasis based library I'm making and my code is dependent on `sexplib` in a totally non-essential way. Is there a way I can provide possible users of this library the choice on whether they would like the extra functionality that comes with the dependency and also easily maintain my code with as little duplication as possible.

Also `cppo` probably doesn't make sense because it's as much of a dependency as `sexplib` is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to move all sexplib dependent code into separate module and package it as a separate ocamlfind (sub)package - it can be a separate cma or just a usual cmo.